# Mean of a periodic velocity field and trajectory displacement bound

Tags: differential-equations, periodic-functions

Suppose $u(t,x)$ is a smooth velocity field on $[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and periodic in space, i.e., $u(t,0)=u(t,1)$ $\forall t$. Assume that $\int_0^1 u(t,x) \,dx = c$, independent of time. Let $x(t)$ be the trajectory with $x(0)=0$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty} \lvert x(t)\rvert/t \le \lvert c\rvert.$ (Alternatively, reduce to the circle and ask about the winding number of a trajectory.)

I'm not sure if this is true, but if it is, it would complete the last step in a theorem I'm trying to prove about the $\mu$-Hunter-Saxton equation. The reason I think it's true is the following elementary argument in the time-independent case: if $u(x)$ has a zero, then some fixed point is attracting and this limit will be zero. Otherwise we can assume $u(x)$ is always positive and compute that the period is $\displaystyle T = \int_0^1 dx/u(x)$. Then by Cauchy-Schwarz we must have $Tc \ge (\int_0^1 \,dx)^2 = 1$, so that $\frac{1}{T}\le c$. But this argument seems cumbersome and doesn't work in the nonautonomous case. Also this seems like a thing that should be well-known.